# Brownian Moment Generating Function and Hitting Times

Tags: probability-theory, brownian-motion, moment-generating-functions

Here is my question. I've done the first part, but I'm stuck on the second. If I can work out (/be advised) how to do the second, then I hope to be able to do the third similarly.

Please note: While I'd really appreciate help on this question, please don't just tell me the answer! I want to learn from the question, so I'd love it if someone would advise me of the next step to take.

[image: AFM 2007 Q3]

I'm really unsure how to proceed at all. Let me write
$$S_a^{-b} = \sup_{0 \le s \le t} (W_s - bs) \;\ \text{and} \;\ \{ T_{a,b} > t \} = \{ S_a^{-b} \le a \}.$$
So we have a nice (well, explicit) expression for $1(T_{a,b} < t)$. However, I can't work out how to combine this with the rest of the expectation. We can say
$$ E(e^{\theta W_t} 1(T_{a,b} < t)) = E(e^{\theta W_t} \mid S_a^{-b} \le a)P(S_a^{-b} \le a),$$
and we have an explicit expression for the latter, but then this first expectation is equally difficult.

We know that $Z_t = \mathcal{E}(\theta W)_t = e^{\theta W_t - \theta^2 t/2}$ defines a UI martingale, and so I hoped to maybe use OST to convert the $e^{\theta W_t}$ into $e^{\theta t/2}$, but I can't see how to do that (or even if that would be a thing). Certainly deriving the third part from the second it looks like it would (/could) use this.

Any advise would be most appreciated. :)

Comment: How about using OST on the stopped martingale $Z_{T_{a,b}\wedge t}$?

Comment: Hm, yeah. Then $T_{a,b} \wedge t = t$ on the indicator in question, and $W_{T_{a,b}} = a + b T_{a,b}$. Still leaves the issue of dealing with the $e^{\mu T_{a,b}} 1(T_{a,b} \le t)$ for $\mu = \theta b - \theta^2/2$ (or something like that)... Should be able to do that using $$E(e^{\mu T_{a,b}} 1(T_{a,b} \le t)) = \int_0^\infty P(e^{\mu T_{a,b}} \ge \lambda) E( 1(T_{a,b} \le t) )d\lambda = \int_0^\infty P( T_{a,b} \ge \log(\lambda)/\mu ) P( T_{a,b} \le t ) d\lambda.$$ I'll give it a try and let you know how it goes. :)

Comment: No, that expectation's not quite right...

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work. That gets the third from the second, but I still can't work out how to get the second... :/